# Azure Storage - How to get the static website URL programmatically?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I've enabled Static Website on my Azure Storage account.

We are uploading files there using the primary service URL (`mycontainer.blob.core.windows.net`), and making those files available using the static website URL (`mycontainer.z6.web.core.windows.net`).

The app has the connection string for the container, for uploading. But I need to know what the resultant public static website URL will be.

Is there any way to programmatically retrieve the static website URL, from within my app,  using the REST API? (I know I can do it with PowerShell or Azure Portal, that's not what I need here.)

The app is hosted in a few different environments, and I don't want to have a separate app config param for both the primary and web endpoints. I should be able to have a single source of truth.

I'm using the Node SDK (`@azure/storage-blob`). I see there's a way to do it with `@azure/arm-storage`, but that would require a different authentication method so is not great.

I'm even prepared to stitch it together myself, but I need a way to figure out what the `z6` (in the example) is going to be.

Comment: Have you thought about using the CDN layer ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/static-website-content-delivery-network#enable-azure-cdn-for-your-static-website you could then choose the static url

Comment: @QuentinGeff yup that might have been my next try. It just seemed a bit stupid that there's no way to retrieve this info

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the web endpoint thanks to the storage account REST API : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storage-accounts/get-properties#storageaccountgetproperties

Response example :

```json
{
  "id": "/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/res9407/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/sto8596",
  "kind": "Storage",
  "location": "eastus2(stage)",
  "name": "sto8596",
  "properties": {
    "keyCreationTime": {
      "key1": "2021-03-18T04:42:22.4322836Z",
      "key2": "2021-03-18T04:42:22.4322836Z"
    },
    "geoReplicationStats": {
      "status": "Live",
      "lastSyncTime": "2018-10-30T00:25:34Z",
      "canFailover": true
    },
    "isHnsEnabled": true,
    "creationTime": "2017-06-01T02:42:41.7633306Z",
    "networkAcls": {
      "bypass": "AzureServices",
      "defaultAction": "Allow",
      "ipRules": [],
      "virtualNetworkRules": [],
      "resourceAccessRules": [
        {
          "tenantId": "72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47",
          "resourceId": "/subscriptions/a7e99807-abbf-4642-bdec-2c809a96a8bc/resourceGroups/res9407/providers/Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/testworkspace"
        }
      ]
    },
    "primaryEndpoints": {
      "web": "https://sto8596.web.core.windows.net/",
      "dfs": "https://sto8596.dfs.core.windows.net/",
      "blob": "https://sto8596.blob.core.windows.net/",
      "file": "https://sto8596.file.core.windows.net/",
      "queue": "https://sto8596.queue.core.windows.net/",
      "table": "https://sto8596.table.core.windows.net/",
      "microsoftEndpoints": {
        "web": "https://sto8596-microsoftrouting.web.core.windows.net/",
        "dfs": "https://sto8596-microsoftrouting.dfs.core.windows.net/",
        "blob": "https://sto8596-microsoftrouting.blob.core.windows.net/",
        "file": "https://sto8596-microsoftrouting.file.core.windows.net/",
        "queue": "https://sto8596-microsoftrouting.queue.core.windows.net/",
        "table": "https://sto8596-microsoftrouting.table.core.windows.net/"
      },
      "internetEndpoints": {
        "web": "https://sto8596-internetrouting.web.core.windows.net/",
        "dfs": "https://sto8596-internetrouting.dfs.core.windows.net/",
        "blob": "https://sto8596-internetrouting.blob.core.windows.net/",
        "file": "https://sto8596-internetrouting.file.core.windows.net/"
      }
    },
    "primaryLocation": "eastus2(stage)",
    "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
    "routingPreference": {
      "routingChoice": "MicrosoftRouting",
      "publishMicrosoftEndpoints": true,
      "publishInternetEndpoints": true
    },
    "encryption": {
      "services": {
        "file": {
          "keyType": "Account",
          "enabled": true,
          "lastEnabledTime": "2019-12-11T20:49:31.7036140Z"
        },
        "blob": {
          "keyType": "Account",
          "enabled": true,
          "lastEnabledTime": "2019-12-11T20:49:31.7036140Z"
        }
      },
      "keySource": "Microsoft.Storage"
    },
    "secondaryLocation": "northcentralus(stage)",
    "statusOfPrimary": "available",
    "statusOfSecondary": "available",
    "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": false
  },
  "sku": {
    "name": "Standard_GRS",
    "tier": "Standard"
  },
  "tags": {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
  },
  "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"
}
```

You can find the url with the following json path : **primaryEndpoints.web**

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this has the info I need, but the frustrating thing is I can't use my storage connection string or the storage SDK to access it, so I'd need to add a whole new library, auth layer, and credentials, just for retrieving the 'z6' :) in which case adding a new app config param with the URL is the lesser evil I think